# Phonegap back button skips page

Tags: android, cordova

I have a very standard Android Phonegap project with the following set up

**index.html:**

```
<a href="http://www.something.com/">One</a>
<a href="test.html">Two</a>
```

**test.html:**

```
<p>Hello.</p>
```

**phonegap.xml:**

```
...
<access origin="http://www.something.com/" subdomains="false" />
...
```

When I run this, I get some odd behaviour with the back buton:

1. Press *One*. I appear at http://www.something.com/, as expected
2. Press the phone's back button. I appear at the the home screen again, as expected
3. Press *Two*. I appear at test.html, as expected
4. Press the phone's back buton. I appear at http://www.something.com/, but **should appear at the home screen** again

Can anyone explain this behaviour? How can I have pressing the back button when on test.html return me to the home screen (where I came from)?

Comment: No, I'm having this error without jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to Phonegap 1.4.0, which happened to be released today, and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share all of your code so it's difficult to judge where is the problem.

But for this application, you will find a solution here:

[Phone-Gap  Redirect One and Two](https://gist.github.com/955496)

If you want more help share your code in brief.

Comment: Where should I be using the backbutton event? I can't modify the contents of http://www.something.com/.

Comment: are you still facing problem then share your wholecode  for it.

Answer (score 0):

Override the back key like this to get back to home page or where ever you want to go

```
function init() {
     document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDR, false);
     }
function onDR(){
     document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, true);     
     }
function backKeyDown() {
     alert('go back!');
     }
```

Comment: Where should I be using the backbutton event? I can't modify the contents of http://www.something.com/.